# Who was Saint Raynerius of Beaulieu?

Tags: catholicism, eastern-orthodox, reference-request, hagiography

I came accross a website about [Saint Raynerius of Beaulieu](https://catholicreadings.org/catholic-quotes/saint-raynerius-of-beaulieu-saint-of-the-day-february-22/). Every source I can find tells me that his feast day is on Feb 22, and that he died in 967 AD. I want to find more information, but have no idea where to start! Please help!

Comment: https://tenthmedieval.wordpress.com/tag/limoges/

Comment: Which country are you from? This may aid us in further help for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Who was Saint Raynerius of Beaulieu?**

[St. Raynerius](https://www.catholic.org/saints/saint.php?saint_id=4565) was Benedictine monk. He served at Beaulieu, near Limoges, France and died in 967. His feast day is celebrated on February 22.

The above information is about the most you will be able to glean off the internet.

One source has this to add:

> Let me introduce you to the Blessed Rainer.
>
> Rainer’s cult doesn’t seem to have stuck, but a man called Remi wanted it to and at some point in the reign of King Lothar III (954-967) he gave Beaulieu a manse in Oriols (in Davazac in the Limousin) for the benefit of his own soul and someone called Robert, and:
>
> > “in honour of the blessed Rainer who was provost of the selfsame place already said, and because of this, that the selfsame man showed his great virtue to all who were there present, when a crippled adolescent who had been brought to his tomb, through the great felicity of his intercession, quickly came running before the altar of Saint Peter; and this great miracle was produced on the feast of Saint Martial.”
>
> This is almost all we get on Rainer; one other charter from 968 refers to a church or altar of St-Rainer that had already received some of the testator’s land in a place called Flexo in Puy d’Arnac, right by the monastery, so perhaps he was moved out into his own chapel, and that’s the last notice as far as I know (not that I have gone looking).2 Even here there are some interesting questions, though. Why didn’t the monks keep him, if he was already a focus of popular devotion? (Presumably one doesn’t dump one’s invalids in front of a nobody’s tomb when there’s an altar of St Peter nearby…) Why is it on the feast of Saint Martial (who was culted not here but at the local diocesan of Limoges) that all this occurred? It may be that, since this was a monastic church, people simply couldn’t access it except on feast days, of course, and the house’s ties to its bishops were usually pretty good early on so an open house for Beaulieu on St Martial’s in recognition of that is not implausible. - [How a saint’s cult gets started](https://tenthmedieval.wordpress.com/tag/limoges/)

It seems that St. Raynier is one of those saints we know very little about. But let that not hinder you in order to try to find more information of this saint from Beaulieu.

Allow me to suggest three approaches in aiding you in your endeavour:

- [The Bollandists](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bollandist) is probably your best bet. That is if you can find the the Lives of the Saints by the [Bollandists](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/02630a.htm). I can not recall how many volumes are in this, but I believe it to be around 18. ***If one can this saint anywhere, it will be here.*** These are hard to find books, so I suggest you try at some traditional Catholic Religious Orders, especially Benedictines.
- Write or email the [Diocese of Limoges](http://www.diocese-limoges.fr/contact/) with a request for further information.
- Use **google search engine in French** (en Français of course) while employing various alternatives of spelling St. Raynerius’ name. This may be the least likely way to be of help, but it is a possibility anyway.

Good luck and hope this help.